# I am trying to communicate with electronic devices,i can connect and send commands to it, but can't receive any message back , How can i solve this?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

//My app is communicating with devices via a wifi module. I can connect and send messages. But can't receive any message back. This is my code. 
**can any one provide a soluton for this...**

ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

```
   View.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String textAddress = IPAddress;
            chatClientThread = new ChatClientThread(textAddress, SocketServerPORT);
            chatClientThread.start();
            thredstart();
        }
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void thredstart()
    {
        UIHandler = new Handler();
        this.Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        this.Thread1.start();
    }

    class Thread1 implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                String SERVERIP=IPAddress;

                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SocketServerPORT);

                Thread2 commThread = new Thread2(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    class Thread2 implements Runnable {


        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public Thread2(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();
                    if(read != null) {
                        UIHandler.post(new UIThread(read));
                    }
                    else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------

    //------------------------------------------------


 private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {

        //String name;
        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;

        String msgToSend = "";
        boolean goOut = false;
        ChatClientThread(String address, int port) {

            dstAddress = address;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=null;

            DataInputStream dataInputStream=null;
           BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                 socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());




//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                while (!goOut) {
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                      msgLog = dataInputStream.readUTF();


                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               text.setText(msgLog);
                           }
                       });
                   }


                    if (!msgToSend.equals("")) {
                       bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dataOutputStream));
                        bufferedWriter.write(msgToSend);
                        //bufferedWriter.close();
                        bufferedWriter.flush();
                        msgToSend = "";
                    }
               }



//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        public void disconnect() {
            goOut=true;

        }

        public void sendMsg(String msg) {
            msgToSend = msg;

        }


    }
    class UIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public UIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText( msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You start two client threads. Why? And why do you post code gor three clients?

Comment: You are complaining that you cant receive messages back. Of course you can. You should only read them from the input stream. You are not using that stream now.

Comment: actuly i just removed readline before adding the code here... am updated my code now... but not working.. @greenapps

Comment: You are not reacting on my first comment.